# How to catch the value of string on a EditText?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, android-edittext

I'am doing a login that has a code of the user and a password. Then, when the fields will be completed, there's a button "log in" that was set.Enabled(false) and it will be set.Enabled(true) allowing the acces ( I did this for to avoid test of consistency).

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText codigo;
    final TextView nome;
    final EditText senha;

    codigo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cod_edit_text);
    senha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.senha_edit_text);

    String cod = codigo.getEditableText().toString();
    String password = senha.getEditableText().toString();

    final Button botaologar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_logar);
    if(!cod.isEmpty() || !password.isEmpty())
    {
        botaologar.setClickable(true);
        botaologar.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        botaologar.setEnabled(false);
        botaologar.setClickable(false);
    }
```

However, when I catch a string of the EditText it is empty by some reason and the button still set.Enabled(false).

I noticed, then, when i named on XML of the activity_main.xml with a string on string.XML with some value, the button stays set.Enabled(true), but the value appears on EditText with the values of the string.xml. Look:

File activity_main.xml:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"

    android:text="@string/cod_edit_text"

    android:id="@+id/cod_edit_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/codigo_text_view"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/senha_edit_text"

    android:text="@string/senha_edit_text"

    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:password="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/senha_text_view"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

File string.xml:

```
<string name="cod_edit_text"> test </string>
<string name="senha_edit_text"> test  </string>
```

So, the problem is that I can't the button stays .setEnabled(true) because I can't to take the value of the EditText correctly. Any idea to solve the problem?

Comment: have you used TextWatcher to listen to text edit event on your edittext? from your code, it looks like the if-else is only executed on activity create.. never while you are typing

Comment: also, i specifically do not know what getEditableText() does, but usually getText() is used to get the contents

Comment: The code you've shown is for your `onCreate(...)` method which is only called once when the `Activity` is created and *BEFORE* your users even get a chance to enter any text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way, but you can definitely use one or two TextWatcher to update whenever there has something changed and/or if the string isn't empty:

```
codigo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        cod = s.toString();
        if(!cod.isEmpty() || !password.isEmpty())
        {
            botaologar.setClickable(true);
            botaologar.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            botaologar.setEnabled(false);
            botaologar.setClickable(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

The same for the editText of the password.

Answer (score 2):

Use **TextWatcher** :

**Example**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private EditText passwordEditText;
private TextView textView;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /* Initializing views */
    passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passwordHint);
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    /* Set Text Watcher listener */
    passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(passwordWatcher);
 }

 private final TextWatcher passwordWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (s.length() == 0) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else{
            textView.setText("You have entered : " + passwordEditText.getText());
        }
    }
 };
}
```

You can always enable or disable the button in TextWatcher's beforeTextChanged or afterTextChanged. Based on your requirements.